# Rust: Vec<(String, Enum)> into an array

Tags: rust

I found [numerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29570607/is-there-a-good-way-to-convert-a-vect-to-an-array) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49328371/how-to-convert-a-vec-into-an-array-without-copying-the-elements) related to converting vectors into arrays, but all deal with simple types inside the vector, which in my case doesn't work.

I have a `Vec<(String, PayloadType)>` where `PayloadType` is a rich enum.

I need to convert it into an array `[(String, PayloadType), _]`.

Some attempts:

`try_into()`:

```
492 |         Payload::from(v[..].try_into().unwrap())
    |                             ^^^^^^^^ the trait `TryFrom<&[(String, mpl_token_auth_rules::payload::PayloadType)]>` is not implemented for `[(String, mpl_token_auth_rules::payload::PayloadType); _]`
```

`into_inner()`:

```
492 |         Payload::from(v.into_inner().unwrap())
    |                         ^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `Vec<(String, mpl_token_auth_rules::payload::PayloadType)>`
```

What's the right way to do it?

PS, the broader goal is to convert a hashmap like this:

```
pub struct Payload {
    map: HashMap<String, PayloadType>,
}
```

into an array like this:

```
[(String, PayloadType); N]
```

I went about it by converting it to Vec first, but open to a better way.

Comment: Do you mean an *array* (i.e. an owned, statically-sized collection of data), or a *slice* (that is, a borrowed collection of contiguous data of potentially dynamic size)? If it's the former, you can't, because you don't statically know the size of the array. If it's the latter, `&v[..]` gets you all the way there. And consider whether a vector works for your use case to begin with. `Vec` is literally designed to be "array of dynamic size" and supports many of the same operations.

Comment: Just remove `[..]` from your first attempt, you can `try_into` vecs into arrays, not references to slices into arrays. See this [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6e8781ab8a0ab9d1c149682186bf8eef)

Comment: @Sil yes you can `try_into` a `Vec` into an array, it will return the original `Vec` if it doesn't have the correct number of items.

Comment: you hate vector of what ?